# Webpack error when importing CSS vendor library into index.js

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, node-modules

I am moving existing javascript vendor libraries into a webpack setup, where possible using npm to install an npm module and deleting the old script tag on the individual page as bundle.js and bundle.css include it

In index.js, I have the following

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

However, when webpack is run, it errors with the following

```
Module parse failed: .......Unexpected character ''
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

So, for some reason, webpack is looking at the entire materialize folder, rather than just the single minified css file, and is then error when it comes across materialize/fonts directory.

I am unclear why this is happening, and what to do to stop it.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My webpack config is below

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
var precss       = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var postcssImport = require('postcss-import');

module.exports = {

  context: __dirname + '/frontend',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static')
},
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', '!css-loader?sourceMap&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("si-styles.css")
  ],
   postcss: function(webpack) {
        return [
            postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }), // Must be first item in list
            precss,
            autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions']  })
        ];
    },

}
```

Comment: Please post your webpack config..

Comment: Updated, thanks Dominic

Comment: It's more common practive for development to serve the css from memory and use ExtractTextPlugin for release building (but that's not the reason). Try removing the `!` from the start of `!css-loader` (not sure if that's the reason but it shouldn't be there anyway), also you can remove `-loader` from all the loaders

Comment: Hi Dominic, thanks, I have removed exclamation mark and -loader,  but unfortunately still the same issue...

Comment: ` loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style!css"
            }]`     Isn't it working ?

Comment: Hi Venky, slightly unclear what you mean, but I have tried removing ExtractTextPlugin from the {test: ....} and it still get the original error.. Thanks for your help